# How to run local Tron Nile node for development porpuses?

Tags: testing, cryptocurrency, tron, trx

What I have done:

I have run fullnode jar with command

```
$ java -Xmx10g -jar FullNode.jar -c nile_config.conf
```

2. nile_config.conf taken from here https://nileex.io/join/getJoinPage without any changes
3. [2000 TRX transferred from faucet](https://nile.tronscan.org/?_gl=1*1v6zoiw*_ga*MTU3NzAxNTQxNi4xNzA0MDQwNzAw*_ga_TBLE5BZDE8*MTcwNDEyNzcxNy4zLjAuMTcwNDEyNzcyMi41NS4wLjA.#/transaction/8f27217f141163bec08ab648af9158a1cd0ca5baaa46e4da8e83e14142b2e0e5)
4. I am connected tronlink wallet to local node to this ports { fullNodePort = 8090 solidityPort = 8091 }

Problem is that when I am using default Nile node from internet, I am able to see both balance and transactions history. But when I am switching to local node I am able to see only balance, but not transactions history. And I am unable to send any transactions whem I am using local node because I got an error that first I need to receive some TRX (which I have in fact).

I guess I am lack some of the APIs for tronlink to use, question which exactly? Any help please?